# SELECT COUNT(*) NO RETURN A NUMBER

Tags: sql-server

I have the following problem when performing a count (*) of a temporary table.
It does not return a number, it returns an asterisk (*). Attached code to see if you can guide me in seeing what is happening. Thank you so much.

```
DECLARE @COUNT_NUM INTEGER;

CREATE TABLE #PRODUCTS_DIM
( PRODUCT VARCHAR(20)
);

INSERT INTO #PRODUCTS_DIM
SELECT PRODUCT
FROM PRODUCTS_TABLE
WHERE PRODUCT IS NOT NULL;

CREATE INDEX IDX_PRODUCT ON #PRODUCTS_DIM(PRODUCT); 


SELECT @COUNT_NUM = COUNT(*) FROM #PRODUCTS_DIM;

PRINT 'VALUE : '+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),@COUNT_NUM );
```

---

RETURN:

```
VALUE  : *
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change the size:

```
 PRINT 'VALUE : '+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(200),@COUNT_NUM );
                           -- here
```

When the value of `@COUNT_NUM` is longer than number of characters then `*` is returned.

```
Value: 1
Value: 10
Value: 99
Value: *     (for 100)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just another option is `concat()` and you don't have to worry about the length.

```
Print concat('Value : ',@Count_Num)
```